# Can we get a Oracle Value with quotes

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get a value in Oracle SQl with Quotes
Example

```
SQL: SELECT mrpid from demandbasic;

MRPID
------------
DEM#000001
```

I need to get the result as

```
MRPID
------------
'DEM#000001'
```

how to get the result as it is desired

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the way, there is an alternate way to quote in SQL (starting with 10gR2), it's called the Q-quote mechanism. You can do this:

```
select q'[']' || mrpid || q'[']' from demandbasic;
```

Using normal quoting as described in Michael's answer makes more sense in simple examples like this one but the q-quote technique is more convenient to use if the quoted text itself contains single quotes.

Related links:
[The Q-quote mechanism](http://awads.net/wp/2006/03/30/the-q-quote-mechanism/)
[Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_sqltypes.htm#sthref377)

Comment: Interesting new featurette.  Your answer shows one snag: most editors' with syntax markers won't handle it, so all the code between two `q'[']'` invocation shows up as a string value.  Compare your answer with Michael's.

Answer (score 8):

Just concatenate it with escaped quotes:

```
SELECT '''' || mrpid || '''' AS mrpid FROM demandbasic;
```

Four single-quotes `''''` is one string literal single-quote.  That is, one quote escaped as `''` and surrounded in quotes to be a string literal.